# Why do you "devour" a prey?

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

> In seventeenth-century France, private and public opinion portrayed
>   the physician as a vulture of greed, circling the sick and dying,
>   battening off the suffering of the afflicted, and ___________________
>   the remains of his prey.

A) spending
B) devouring
C) retreating from
D) decrying
E) resorbing

I thought the correct answer was 'spending' because of these keywords 'vulture', 'circling', 'batten' are directly support it. But the answer is *b*

Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Why would the answer be *spending*?

Comment: I didn't realise batten had a meaning beyond being a strip of material used to hold something in place 'Batten down the hatches!' TIL (Old French vs Old Norse roots for the disparate meanings)

Comment: Don't you hate it when it's just a week after payday and your vultures have already spent all of your wages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to pass a test rather than how to use the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the object of the verb in question. You can't spend remains (unless you have some meat-based monetary system), nor can they be resorbed, because they are a separate entity to any subject acting on them, as they are the remnants of another, here specified by 'his prey.' (a ghost might refer to 'my remains' in fiction but then the ghost and its remains are separate objects)

Ok, so now you have:

> B) devouring
>
> C) retreating from
>
> D) decrying

If you look at their basic meanings:

> B) eat
>
> C) move away from
>
> D) publicly denounce

If we look again at the keywords you have identified:

> Vulture: a carrion bird that eats the flesh of dead animals
>
> Circling: the subject's movement describes a circle around the object
>
> Batten: thrive or prosper at the expense of

A vulture is said to circle its prey, where its 'prey' is an already dead or imminently dead animal (through injury or sickness), it is not prone to retreating from (in fact is notorious for not doing so) nor denouncing its food (if a vulture even could denounce anything).

You have identified good keywords which do help work out which answer is correct, but the missing step was to look up their meanings and so see how they relate to each other.